# Remove double quotes from string in java

Tags: android, retrofit2

I want to send a post request in retrofit2 that have body with string field. But when string have double quotes server return error. When i have remove double quotes in postman everything is good(i can do it there). My strin field is an uuid. I used uuid instead of string but double qoutes dont removed.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please post some code, solution can provided according to that issue by looking in to code.

Comment: if you are sending JSON, fix your server. Otherwise, don't use retrofit.

Comment: _"But when string have double quotes server return error."_ What type of error? Any stack trace of the error?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String removeDoubleQuota(String szLine){
        if(szLine == null){
            return null;
        }
         if(szLine.startsWith("\"")&&szLine.endsWith("\"")){
             szLine=szLine.substring(1,szLine.length()-1);
         }
         return szLine;
    }
```